# How to get ListView to grow to the size of content

Tags: android, listview

So I have a fairly complex activity the parent being a linearlayout with a table with some basic info and buttons. Then a couple listviews that the user can add items to. So these listviews grow more and more as the user uses the app. The problem I'm running into is the Linearlayout is bigger then the resolution of the screen and so it needs to scroll. So the scrolling doesn't work on the Listviews. I've tried playing with changing the layout_height of the listview and its child element with no success. Is there a way to make these couple listviews expand out to the amount of children? Or am I going about this all wrong? If so what other controls can I use?

I'm open to any ideas. I really just don't know how to go about this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem I'm running into is the
>   Linearlayout is bigger then the
>   resolution of the screen and so it
>   needs to scroll. So the scrolling
>   doesn't work on the Listviews.

You need to rethink the way you are building your UI, as you cannot have `ListViews` inside of a `ScrollView`.

One possibility is to put everything in the `ListView`, marking some rows as being non-clickable, so `ListView` handles your scrolling. You can use my [`MergeAdapter`](http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge) for cases like this.

Comment: So I have a very complex views above my lists. Its all defined in one xml view how would I go about adding these components into the MergeAdapter? Should I create all my controls at runtime? or how should I go about this?

Comment: Define a layout XML file with the stuff that should go into the `ListView` before the contents of your regular adapter. Inflate that at runtime using `getLayoutInflater().inflate()`. Add that `View` to the `MergeAdapter`, then add your regular `Adapter`. Then put the `MergeAdapter` in the `ListView`. Once you have that working, extend the `MergeAdapter` to override the proper methods to indicate that your first "row" isn't selectable/clickable.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a simple layout then you can replace your `ListView` component with a `LinearLayout` and manually program together the functionality you need to add/remove and click the items within it.

Here is a simple example of my own. `refreshStudentList()` has taken the place of `notifyDataSetChanged()` being called on the adapter, `recentConnections` is a `LinearLayout` and `adapter` is an instance of an `Adapter` (You can use the adapter you were using for your `ListView`):

```
private void refreshStudentList() {
    recentConnections.removeAllViews();

    for(int i=0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View toAdd = adapter.getView(i, null, recentConnections);
        final int position = i;
        toAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // onItemClick functionality here
            }
        });

        recentConnections.addView(toAdd, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
                (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 50, getResources().getDisplayMetrics())));
    }

    recentConnections.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}
```

As you can see, instead of an `onItemClickListener` I've set a `onClick` listener to each list item. This could easily be changed to be an `onTouch` listener if you wanted to implement the look and feel of clicking on a list item (by changing the view's background on `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` and `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`).

The other thing you need to note is I have hard coded a dp value for the height of each value (`50dp` in this case). When you are creating and inflating views programatically they don't have a "height" value so "wrap_content" becomes 0.

also, `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter will do nothing.

As I said, this is a simple solution but it's the start of building up your own ExtendingListView custom component if that's what you're eventually aiming for.